# Network changes lost on quick hard reboot

Tags: windows-10, network-adapter, netsh

On Windows 10, if I change the IP address and perform a hard reboot a few seconds later (cut the power and restart after some momemts) the change does not persist, i.e. the IP address is back to what it was before I changed it. In contrast, if I wait for approximately a minute between changing the address and the hard shutdown, the change will persist.

I tried changing the IP address using both netsh and the control panel GUI with the same results. For reference, the netsh command I use is `netsh interface ipv4 set address "Ethernet" static address=The.New.Ip`

It very much looks like the address changes are not "saved" immediately, but can anyone clear up what is the case exactly? And is there any way to force Windows to do this "saving" immediately?

Comment: Why not leave it dynamic on the client and give it a static address on the router? This will also eliminate the chance of collisions due to (for example) config typos on other connected hardware.

Answer (score 0):

*Most* operating systems, including Windows, cache writes to the SSD or HHD to make the process more efficient. If one shuts the PC *before* the cache in RAM is written to the internal drive, those changes are lost.

However, you can [control write caching](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/backup-and-storage/turn-disk-write-caching-on-off) for each disk. For example, because a flash USB drive might need to be removed abruptly, write-caching is turned *off* by default (though it is still a very bad idea to unplug a USB drive without "safely ejecting").

**N.B.** Though you *can* turn off write-caching on your main drive, t achieve the effect you want (being able to power down quickly and retain data), there are two issues with this:

1. This will  s l o w  writing to disk. If you must do this, turn caching back on after rebooting.
2. There still is a finite time to write data; you'll need to wait a few seconds before powering down.

All this neglects the question: **Why** would you need to force a hard reboot by powering down, which is likely to corrupt the HDD or SSD???